# Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization on SerializationUtils.clone()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, security, fortify

I am getting Fortify issue **Dynamic Code Evaluation: Unsafe Deserialization** on the lines below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/v2/doc", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public JsonDocVerifyResponse verify(@RequestBody JsonDocVerifyRequestV3 request)
```

```
JsonDocVerifyRequestV3 temp = (JsonDocVerifyRequestV3)SerializationUtils.clone(request);
```

The solution for unsafe deserialization is this https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-lookahead/
But as you can see in my codes I am not using ByteArrayOutputStream to deserialize the object.

Is this a false positive by Fortify? If not, how can I use

```
org.apache.commons.io.serialization.ValidatingObjectInputStream
```

to validate the class? Any code sample will be of great help!

These are the snippets:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value="/v2/doc", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public JsonDocVerifyResponse verify(@RequestBody JsonDocVerifyRequestV3 request) {

        debugJsonRequest(request, DOC_TYPE.khIdBack);

        JsonDocVerifyResponse response = new JsonDocVerifyResponse();

        return response;
    }
   public void debugJsonRequest(JsonDocVerifyRequestV3 request, DOC_TYPE docType) {

        try {

          JsonDocVerifyRequestV3 temp(JsonDocVerifyRequestV3) SerializationUtils.clone(request);

          LOGGER.debug("{}|{}", docType, CommonUtil.debugJsonObject(temp));

        } catch(Exception e) {
         LOGGER.error("Error in debug json object", e);
        }

 }
```

Comment: Could you share the `request` variable details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `accept` and `reject` methods to safer deserialization operation.

Example:

```java
import com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import org.apache.commons.io.serialization.ValidatingObjectInputStream;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Bar bar = new Bar("bar-test");
        Foo foo = new Foo("test-foo", bar);

        // write into an array buffer
        ByteArrayBuffer buffer = new ByteArrayBuffer();
        try (ObjectOutputStream serializeStream = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer)) {
            serializeStream.writeObject(foo);
        }

        try (ValidatingObjectInputStream stream = new ValidatingObjectInputStream(buffer.newInputStream())) {
            // add validated classes
            stream.accept(Foo.class);
            stream.accept(Bar.class);


            Foo foo2 = (Foo) stream.readObject();
            System.out.println(foo2);
        }
    }

    public static class Foo implements Serializable {
        private String name;
        private Bar bar;

        public Foo(String name, Bar bar) {
            this.name = name;
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", bar=" + bar +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static class Bar implements Serializable {
        private String name;

        public Bar(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bar{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks I used your suggestion and can validate the classes successfully! :D

However Fortify is still not marking the issue as Fixed. I updated the description with further snippets. 

I also updated the lines triggering the unsafe deserialization.

Is there anything else we can do at the controller method `verify()` to validate the `request`?

Answer (score 0):

The fortify issue makes sense since `SerializationUtils.clone` first deserialize and then serialize the content into a new object.

A work around I found for this specific scenario with cloning is to use other deep clone library. here is an example.

```
public void deepClone() {
    User pm = new User("Kevin", "13", "test@test.com");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    //Deep clone object
    User deepCopy = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(pm), User.class);
}
```

With this method the class you want to clone eg. User.Class doesn't need to implement `Serializable`